# What size should I scale my sprites to before importing them to Unity?

Tags: unity, sprites

I'm developing a game with an 8bit look. I want to target iOS and Android devices.

The real resolution for my backgrounds is 108 x 192.

Should I should put them in that same resolution and scale them in Unity using FilterMode / or s there a way to make the camera use nearest neighbor?

Or should I resize all my sprites before importing to something bigger? And if so to what size? 1920 x 1080?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to weigh the cost / benefit of loading larger assets into your project verses dealing with scaled game objects within a scene.  Personally I keep my assets at actual size, smaller the better and throw them into a sprite sheet, and scale them up within the editor.  FilterMode Point is so crunchy works just fine for me! and from everything I have experienced the performance hit from scaled game objects is negligible.

The best thing you can do is actually take a look at `Static Batching` here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html which would have much more potential for improved performance.

Overall targeting a phone, I would want to keep my assets as small as possible.

Comment: hi @Joe, I understand I will use all my assets with their real (small) sizes. My question is do I need to resize each sprite with FilterMode.Point or can I put them in a GameObject and scale them all at once? let me know if the question is not clear

Comment: I just posted a related question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99321/resize-sprite-to-match-camera-width