# Resize sprite to match camera width?

Tags: unity, sprites, scale

I'm trying to resize my small background sprite to match the screen width of the user's device.

This is what I'm trying

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    // Set filterMode
    SpriteRenderer sr = (SpriteRenderer) GetComponent("Renderer");
    sr.sprite.texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

    // Get scaling
    float multiplier = Camera.main.rect.width / sr.sprite.bounds.size.x;

    // Scale
    transform.localScale = localScale * multiplier;
}
```

It seems there is a problem with the measure I get from the Camera width, I also tried Screen.width but it seems it returns the value in pixels.

Answer (score 4):

This functions should scale the sprite proportionally so it fits the camera width:

```
void fitCameraWidth() {
    SpriteRenderer sr = (SpriteRenderer)GetComponent ("Renderer");
    if (sr == null)
        return;

    // Set filterMode
    sr.sprite.texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

    // Get stuff
    double width = sr.sprite.bounds.size.x;
    Debug.Log ("width: " + width);
    double worldScreenHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2.0;
    double worldScreenWidth = worldScreenHeight / Screen.height * Screen.width;

    // Resize
    transform.localScale = new Vector2 (1, 1) * (float)(worldScreenWidth / width);
}
```

If what you want to do if resize to fit the camera height (if your game is played in landscape this is probably what you would want):

```
void fitCameraHeight() {
    SpriteRenderer sr = (SpriteRenderer)GetComponent ("Renderer");
    if (sr == null)
        return;

    // Set filterMode
    sr.sprite.texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

    // Get stuff
    double width = sr.sprite.bounds.size.x;
    double worldScreenHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2.0;

    // Resize
    transform.localScale = new Vector2 (1, 1) * (float)(worldScreenHeight / height);
}
```